# Injecting correct object graph using StructureMap in Queue of different Objects

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, abstract-factory

I have a queuing service that has to inject a different dependency graph depending on the type of object in the queue.  I'm using `Structure Map`.

So, if the object in the queue is `TypeA` the concrete classes for `TypeA` are used and if it's `TypeB`, the concrete classes for `TypeB` are used.

I'd like to avoid code in the queue like:

```
if (typeA)
{
   // setup TypeA graph
}
else if (typeB) {
   // setup TypeB graph
}
```

Within the graph, I also have a generic classes such as an `IReader(ISomething, ISpomethingElse)` where `IReader` is generic but needs to inject the correct `ISomething` and `ISomethingElse` for the type.  `ISomething` will also have dependencies and so on.

Currently I create a `TypeA` or `TypeB` object and inject a generic Processor class using StructureMap into it and then pass a `factory` manually inject a `TypeA` or `TypeB` factory into a method like:

```
Processor.Process(new TypeAFactory)  // perhaps I should have an abstract factory...
```

However, because the factory then creates the generic `IReader` mentioned above, I end up manually injecting all the TypeA or `TypeB` classes fro there on.

I hope enough of this makes sense.

I am new to `StructureMap` and was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction here for a flexible and elegant solution.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I really understand your problem. Could you create some simplified working code example we could work with. Secondly define better what's in the queue. Do you have access to the container there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understand your question, but in general your queue processor needs access to some sort of factory for processing those objects. The most convenient approach would be if your queue consist of messages/commands (DTOs) and you have some sort of abstraction over command handling logic, such as `ICommandHandler<TCommand>`.

In that case your queue processor might look like this:

```cs
private readonly ICommandHandlerFactory factory;

public void Process(IEnumerable<object> commandQueue)
{
    foreach (object command in commandQueue)
    {
        dynamic handler = this.factory.CreateHandlerFor(command.GetType());

        handler.Handle((dynamic)command);
    }
}
```